# Is this question too localized?

Tags: discussion, flagging

The owner of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296486/how-to-change-language-in-13-04-to-english-when-only-installed-language-is-engli) wants help changing the Language for menus and windows from Chinese (which she can't read) to Spanish. Is this question too localized because it is of interest to one person only? Or is it not too localized because it is about using the desktop environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too localized, though IIRC this was a bug in previous versions.

Someone just needs to post the screenshots and direct her on how to do it.

Comment: The question could be improved to something even more usefull, like "how to change the language if you can't read the current one"

Comment: I don't think it is too localized. Seems like a reasonable question. It may not have a lot of interest but I could see how any non-English primary language people would find it useful.